# Single image as tr background

Tags: html, css

What i am trying to do is to set a single image for a complete table row(row contains multiple cells),
How to set a single image for a table row despite of multiple cells in that row ,i am unable to set a single image ,there is individual image in each cell when i set tr background image, please suggest in css, javascript or in jquery

Comment: If you could post some code that you have tried, that would help us identify where you could fix your code. Thanks!

Comment: If not mistaken you need to do `tr td { ... }` as a `tr` tag does not handle background images

Comment: what i have to do is to highlight duplicate rows in a table with an image behind duplicate row "DUPLICATE" ,,,,,while i am doing so ,,, i have failed to fix a single image behind the complete row ,,, in my case image is appearing in each cell ,,,

Answer (score 0):

For a background image on X cells merged on row, use :

```
<td colspan="X" style="background-image:url(untitled.png); background-position:right 0px; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
        Hello World
    </td>
```

replace X with the numbers of columns you want to merge
replace untitled.png with the relative path of your pic

The colspan allow to merge cells horizontally 
And use rowspan if you want to merge vertically